# Facebook-like Notification Plugin for WordPress Community Blog Sites?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, facebook, notifications, community

I am a member of a community blog site run by WordPress engine. But I often feel that if there were a notification system like Facebook tracking the site would be much easier. I know about the notification emails and RSS feeds but those do not serve the whole purpose. I need to have notification when:

- Somebody comments on any of my blog posts.
- Somebody comments after any of my comments in any posts.
- My blog post is rated.

Almost like Facebook. Is there any plugin for that?

Comment: *@Gulshan* - When you say *"I know about the notification emails and RSS feeds but those do not serve the whole purpose"* what kind of notifications do you want for these events if not by RSS or by email?

Comment: My guess would be the same type of system as Facebook: An icon that follows you around the site with a drop-down box showing notifications and a bubble with the number of new notifications in it.

Comment: as @voyagerfan5761 said. Same like facebook.

Comment: The question still is totally unclear. Are there multiple users on that blog doing posts? Where should the bubble of notifications be displayed? On the Admin Dashboard? On the Frontpage? Can you add some screenshots that illustrate what you're asking for?

Comment: @hakre In the site there ARE multiple users on the blog doing posts. The bubble can be displayed at top like facebook, or even like this stackexchange site. In the front page while the user has logged in.

Comment: @Gulshan: Sounds like a plugin request to me then. I assume that the "my" in the question is infact "the current user", right? Which rating plugin are you using? Please leave some information how to contact you personally, the link in your profile is not working.

Answer (score 1):

The BuddyPress bar shows notifications e.g. when someone friends you.

I think you have to search then for BuddyPress plugins that enable your 3 requirements.
and add the code to the filter for the bar on top.

or widget-tify the activity stream per user enriched with whatever more data

Maybe you can even award points for all interaction like here and like the BuddyPress CubePoints plugin

Comment: It would be good to know if BuddyPress is an option for Gulshan. Sounds promising at least.

Answer (score 0):

I can't post a comment yet but just wanted to clarify Edelman's answer.  Out of the box, Buddypress does not have notifications of friend requests as a flag (like (1) on Facebook when there is new activity).  What it does instead is show a count of your total friends.

What you suggest will certainly take some hacking as I don't know of an out-of-the-box solution yet.  You may want to take a look at [Mark as Read](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/mark-as-read/).

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need: Better Notifications for WordPress https://wordpress.org/plugins/bnfw/